# Проблема с компиляцией и вирусами

Tags: python, pyinstaller, virustotal

Создал код, скомпилировал с помощью pyinstaller, скинул другу, он не смог скачать из-за вируса, решил проверить на virustotal, и мне выдало 8 вирусов. Вот и вопрос, это нормально???
Название вирусов:

```
Trojan[PSW]/Python.Agent,
Malicious (score: 100),
Trojan.PWS.Agent!m7rD4I82OUM,
Trojan.PSW.Python.z,
Malicious,
Trojan.Win64.Agent.oa!s1,
Trojan:Win32/CryptInject!ml,
Trojan.Disco.Script.104.
```

P.s. эта программа рассказывает какая погода в городе, основанная на pyowm.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/553288

Comment: нет, ну вы сталкивались с такого рода проблемой? Если да, то не могли бы вы мне сказать это нормально или нет, и если да, то попрошу рассказать из за чего это происходит

Comment: По ссылке выше прямо так и сказано, что это нормально и что антивирусы так реагируют на любые программы написанные на питоне, потому что кто то писал на нем вирусы. А разработчики антивирусов не нашли ничего лучше, чем добавить сигнатуры, общие для большинства скомпилированных python программ к себе в базы

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое.

Comment: В моём случае Antiy-AVL Trojan/Generic.ASMalwS.61
Avast Win32:MalwareX-gen [Trj]
AVG Win32:MalwareX-gen [Trj]
Gridinsoft (no cloud) Ransom.Win32.Wacatac.oa!s1
JiangminTrojan.PSW.Python.ii
ZillyaTrojan.Stealer.Win32.27076